# SQLAlchemy - Max of column among rows with same value in other column

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I have the following a Table **DataUnit** with columns **session_id** (INT) and **timeStamp** (INT). I want to find the maximum value of **timeStamp** for a given value of **session_id**. How to do this in SQLAlchemy?

I can simply query all rows with given **session_id**, order by **timeStamp** and take the first element, but what will be the more efficient way of doing it?

Table definition:-

```
class DataUnit(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'DataUnit'
    dataUnit_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    session_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('Session.session_id'))
    timeStamp = Column(BigInteger())
```

Comment: `Table` or mapped class? Please include the definition. Your database probably has the `MAX()` aggregate function available, so a simple `select max(timeStamp) from DataUnit where session_id = something`, translated to SQLA, should do.

Comment: "Translate to SQLA" - That's the question

Answer (score 2):

Your database probably has the aggregate function `MAX()`, and SQLAlchemy offers a [generic approach to using SQL function expressions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html), the special `func` object. Since you are interested in a scalar value, you can also employ [`Query.scalar()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.scalar), which returns the first column of the first result row, or None. It'd seem like you use Flask-SQLAlchemy, since you inherit from `db.Model`, so here's a method of using [`Model.query`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/api/#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.Model.query) with [`Query.with_entities()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_entities):

```
session_id = 'insert session id here'

max_timestamp = DataUnit.query.\
    filter_by(session_id=session_id).\
    with_entities(db.func.max(DataUnit.timeStamp)).\
    scalar()
```

Efficiency of the query will depend on your database engine and possible indexes available.